# Scraping web page after accepting cookies in python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to scrape a web page but before accessing the page, there is a banner for accepting cookies. I am using selenium to click on the button "Accept all cookies" but even after clicking on the button I can't access the right HTML page.

This is my code :

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://www.wikiparfum.fr/explore/by-name?query=dior'

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=DRIVER_PATH)

driver.get(url)
driver.find_element_by_id('onetrust-accept-btn-handler').click()

html = driver.page_source
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')

print(soup)
```

And this is the beginning of the HTML page that is printed :
[image]

If anyone can help me with this one, thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should wait for the accept cookies button element appearance before clicking it

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://www.wikiparfum.fr/explore/by-name?query=dior'

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=DRIVER_PATH)
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)

driver.get(url)
wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "#onetrust-accept-btn-handler"))).click()

html = driver.page_source
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')

print(soup)
```